# Routing issue with reactjs router 4 and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Hello I' m building a project where I have used reactjs redux and react-router-dom.

For some strange reason that I can't figure out, when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000` I get the following error:
`Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/signin"`

I have tried many things from similar questions but with no luck. Perhaps `Switch` does not work? or I need a fresh pair of eyes because this might be obvious...

Bellow is my source code:

## router.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from '../routes/index.jsx';

// Global Components
import CustomNavbar from '../navbar/index.jsx';
import Sidemenu from '../sidemenu/index.jsx';
import Emulator from '../emulator/index.jsx';

// Styles
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../../sass/style.scss';
import '../../sass/router.scss';

class CustomRouter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    isSignedin = () => {
        return this.props.user.authenticated;
    }

    isSidemenuOpen = () => {
        return this.props.app.sidemenu.open;
    }

    isEmulatorOpen = () => {
        return this.props.app.emulator.open;
    }

    getWrapperClassName = () => {

        let classList = [];

        if (this.isSignedin()) {
            classList.push('authenticated');
        }

        if (this.isSidemenuOpen()) {
            classList.push('sidemenu');
        }

        if (this.isEmulatorOpen()) {
            classList.push('emulator');
        }

        return classList.join(' ');

    }

    render = () => {

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>

                <div id='wrapper' className={this.getWrapperClassName()}>

                    {(() => {

                        if (this.isSignedin()) {

                            return (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    <Sidemenu />
                                    <CustomNavbar />
                                    <Emulator />
                                </React.Fragment>
                            )

                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }

                    })()}

                    <div id='page-content'>
                        <div className='p-4'>
                            <Routes />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </BrowserRouter>
        )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        app: state.appReducer,
        user: state.userReducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { withRef: true })(CustomRouter);
```

## routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import AuthenticatedRoute from '../authenticatedRoute/index.jsx';
import UnauthenticatedRoute from '../unauthenticatedRoute/index.jsx';

// Root Components
import Home from '../routes/home/index.jsx';
import Dashboard from '../routes/dashboard/index.jsx';
import Bots from '../routes/bots/index.jsx';
import Actions from '../routes/actions/index.jsx';
import Flows from '../routes/flows/index.jsx';
import Sessions from '../routes/sessions/index.jsx';
import Users from '../routes/users/index.jsx';
import Signin from '../routes/signin/index.jsx';
import Signup from '../routes/signup/index.jsx';
import Reset from '../routes/reset/index.jsx';
import NotFound from '../routes/notfound/index.jsx';

const Routes = ({ location }) => {
    return (
        <TransitionGroup className='transition-group'>
            <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames='fade' timeout={{ enter: 300, exit: 300 }}>
                <section className='route-group'>
                    <Switch location={location} >
                        <Route path='/' component={Home} exact={true}></Route>
                        <UnauthenticatedRoute path='/signin' component={Signin} exact={true}></UnauthenticatedRoute>
                        <UnauthenticatedRoute path='/signup' component={Signup} exact={true}></UnauthenticatedRoute>
                        <UnauthenticatedRoute path='/reset' component={Reset} exact={true}></UnauthenticatedRoute>
                        {/* <AuthenticatedRoute path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} exact={true}></AuthenticatedRoute>
                        <AuthenticatedRoute path='/bots/:botId?' component={Bots} exact={true}></AuthenticatedRoute>
                        <AuthenticatedRoute path='/actions/:actionId?' component={Actions} exact={true}></AuthenticatedRoute>
                        <AuthenticatedRoute path='/flows/:flowId?' component={Flows} exact={true}></AuthenticatedRoute>
                        <AuthenticatedRoute path='/users/:userId?' component={Users} exact={true}></AuthenticatedRoute>
                        <AuthenticatedRoute path='/sessions/:sessionId?' component={Sessions} exact={true}></AuthenticatedRoute> */}
                        <Route path='*' component={NotFound}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </section>
            </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Routes);
```

## home.jsx (/ dummy route component)

> it is only used to either redirect you to /dashboard or /signin accordingly

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import '../../../sass/home.scss';

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = this.getInitialState();

    }

    getInitialState = () => {
        return {};
    }

    render = () => {

        let { authenticated } = this.props.user;

        if (authenticated) {
            console.log('Redirecting to "/dashboard" from home');
            return (
                <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
            )

        } else {
            console.log('Redirecting to "/signin" from home');
            return (
                <Redirect to="/signin" />
            )

        }

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        app: state.appReducer,
        user: state.userReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(Home);
```

## unauthenticated.jsx

> (for routes that are only accessible when not authenticated)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class UnauthenticatedRoute extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    isSignedin = () => {
        return this.props.user.authenticated;
    }

    render = () => {

        let { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

        console.log('Unauthenticated:', !this.isSignedin() ? `Rendering` : `Redirecting`);

        return (

            <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
                !this.isSignedin() ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                        <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
                    )
            )} />

        )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        app: state.appReducer,
        user: state.userReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {}
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(UnauthenticatedRoute));
```

## authenticated.jsx

> (for routes that are only accessible when authenticated)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class AuthenticatedRoute extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    isSignedin = () => {
        return this.props.user.authenticated;
    }

    render = () => {

        let { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

        console.log('Authenticated:', this.isSignedin() ? `Rendering` : `Redirecting`);

        return (

            <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
                this.isSignedin() ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                        <Redirect to='/signin' />
                    )
            )} />

        )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        app: state.appReducer,
        user: state.userReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {}
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(AuthenticatedRoute));
```

Comment: PS: The problem occurs only when I navigate to '/'. If i navigate to /signin there are no console errors.

Comment: Are you sure that you have not misnamed the components of Authenticated and Unauthenticated. Check please source code and name. If ok please tell the logs(console.logs), that  that appear.

Comment: The only place those 2 are used are inside routes.jsx. Names seem ok since the only unauthenticated routes are signin signup and reset. The '/' route is a simple route component. The logs print the error mentioned in description 5 times

Comment: Haven't worked through the logic on this, but what if `isSignedIn()` called inside nested children `render()`s is always failing because it's not bound to correct `this` context? Does adding `this.isSignedIn = this.isSignedIn.bind(this)` to appropriate constructors help?

Comment: it's not failing because it is declared as an arrow function, and latest babel transpile's it preserving th context, hence you dont need to bind anymore @AndyTaton

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying and separating your protected routes into a single `RequireAuth` component. With the help of `Redux`, we can then expose the routes when the user has been authenticated.

You may be able to get away with using React's `Context` provider, but either way, you'll need to utilize some sort of `HOC` that can pass down its state/methods to children. Otherwise, it's going to be a nested nightmare of HOC state and methods being passed back and forth.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/88qmx06082 (react-router v3 -- one the reasons why I use and prefer v3 because its super easy to nest routes)

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/yqo75n896x (react-router v4)

**routes/index.js** (v4)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Header from "../containers/Header";
import Info from "../components/Info";
import Sponsors from "../components/Sponsors";
import Signin from "../containers/Signin";
import RequireAuth from "../containers/RequireAuth";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
          <Route path="/sponsors" component={Sponsors} />
          <Route path="/protected" component={RequireAuth} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

**containers/RequireAuth.js** (v4)

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ShowPlayerRoster from "../components/ShowPlayerRoster";
import ShowPlayerStats from "../components/ShowPlayerStats";
import Schedule from "../components/Schedule";

const RequireAuth = ({ match: { path }, isAuthenticated }) =>
  !isAuthenticated ? (
    <Redirect to="/signin" />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Route exact path={`${path}/roster`} component={ShowPlayerRoster} />
      <Route path={`${path}/roster/:id`} component={ShowPlayerStats} />
      <Route path={`${path}/schedule`} component={Schedule} />
    </div>
  );

export default connect(state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
}))(RequireAuth);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the following and it was a matter of logic as far as I can tell.There were no multiple components mounting if you might wonder. It had to do with `AuthenticatedRoute` & `UnauthenticatedRoute` component. Also I completely removed `home` component.

## Authenticate render method

```
render = () => {

    let { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (

        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            this.isSignedin() ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                    props.location.pathname === '/signin' ? (null) : (<Redirect to='/signin' />)
                )
        )} />

    )

}
```

## Unauthenticated render method

```
render = () => {

    let { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (

        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            !this.isSignedin() ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                    props.location.pathname === '/' ? (null) : (<Redirect to='/' />)
                )
        )} />

    )

}
```